# Pandas average by varying time intervals and group by columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have this pandas dataset:

| date | a | b | c | d | col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01-12-20 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0.2 |
| 02-12-20 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 2 | 0.4 |
| 03-12-20 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 5 | 5 |
| 03-12-20 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 6 | 1 |
| 03-12-20 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 5 | 1 |
| 05-12-20 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 2 | 0.3 |
| 07-12-20 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 3 | 6 |
| 08-12-20 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 8 | 7 |
| 08-12-20 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 7 | 1 |
| 10-12-20 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 4 | 1 |
| 11-12-20 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 3 | 0 |

and the following list of time intervals

```
from datetime import date
timeintervals = [date(2020, 12, 1), date(2020, 12, 3), date(2020, 12, 7), date(2020, 12, 11), date(2020, 12, 21)]
groupcol = ["a","b","c","d"]
```

I need to obtain a new dataset where:

- I get the average of col1 and col2, grouped by time interval and by the columns listed in the groupcol variable (considering only rows with 1 and not with zeros).
  It is like saying the average of "a" for each time interval, when "a" is 1. If "a" has all zeros in an interval, the resulting average value should be zero.
- name of column "abcd" can be any name;
- to define time intervals we consider the provided list such that `timeintervals[i] <= date < timeintervals[i+1]` and proceed recursively;
- time intervals in the grouped df are labeled by their upperbound minus one day.

The result should be this:

| date | abcd | col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 02-12-20 | a | 0 | 0 |
| 02-12-20 | b | 0 | 0 |
| 02-12-20 | c | 0 | 0 |
| 02-12-20 | d | 0 | 0 |
| 06-12-20 | a | 6 | 1 |
| 06-12-20 | b | 5.5 | 1 |
| 06-12-20 | c | 0 | 0 |
| 06-12-20 | d | 0 | 0 |
| 10-12-20 | a | 3 | 6 |
| 10-12-20 | b | 8 | 7 |
| 10-12-20 | c | 5 | 3.5 |
| 10-12-20 | d | 8 | 7 |
| 20-12-20 | a | 0 | 0 |
| 20-12-20 | b | 0 | 0 |
| 20-12-20 | c | 0 | 0 |
| 20-12-20 | d | 3 | 0 |

I am having trouble finding an efficient solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

Let us do it in steps

First we add a column that specifies which group we allocate each date to

```
df['dgr'] = df['date'].apply(lambda d: [d.date()<l for l in timeintervals].index(True)-1)
df
```

to obtain

```
    date                   a    b    c    d    col1    col2    dgr
--  -------------------  ---  ---  ---  ---  ------  ------  -----
 0  2020-12-01 00:00:00    0    0    0    0       1     0.2      0
 1  2020-12-02 00:00:00    0    0    0    0       2     0.4      0
 2  2020-12-03 00:00:00    0    0    0    0       5     5        1
 3  2020-12-03 00:00:00    1    1    0    0       6     1        1
 4  2020-12-03 00:00:00    0    1    0    0       5     1        1
 5  2020-12-05 00:00:00    0    0    0    0       2     0.3      1
 6  2020-12-07 00:00:00    1    0    1    0       3     6        2
 7  2020-12-08 00:00:00    0    1    0    1       8     7        2
 8  2020-12-08 00:00:00    0    0    1    0       7     1        2
 9  2020-12-10 00:00:00    0    0    0    0       4     1        2
10  2020-12-11 00:00:00    0    0    0    1       3     0        3
```

The following command prepares the 'skeleton' of the final result -- basically unrolls a,b,c,d into a column and keeps tracks of 0,1s in the original df

```
df2 = (df[groupcol]
    .stack()
    .reset_index(level = 1)
    .rename(columns = {'level_1' : 'abcd',0:'incl'})
)
df2
```

to get

```
    abcd      incl
--  ------  ------
 0  a            0
 0  b            0
 0  c            0
 0  d            0
 1  a            0
 1  b            0
 1  c            0
 1  d            0
 2  a            0
 2  b            0
 2  c            0
 2  d            0
 3  a            1
 3  b            1
 3  c            0
 3  d            0
 4  a            0
 4  b            1
 4  c            0
 4  d            0
 5  a            0
 5  b            0
 5  c            0
 5  d            0
 6  a            1
 6  b            0
 6  c            1
 6  d            0
 7  a            0
 7  b            1
 7  c            0
 7  d            1
 8  a            0
 8  b            0
 8  c            1
 8  d            0
 9  a            0
 9  b            0
 9  c            0
 9  d            0
10  a            0
10  b            0
10  c            0
10  d            1
```

Now we can join df2 with df to fill in the date,col1, col2 details

```
df2 = df2.join(df[['date','col1','col2','dgr']])
```

to get

```
    abcd      incl  date                   col1    col2    dgr
--  ------  ------  -------------------  ------  ------  -----
 0  a            0  2020-12-01 00:00:00       1     0.2      0
 0  b            0  2020-12-01 00:00:00       1     0.2      0
 0  c            0  2020-12-01 00:00:00       1     0.2      0
 0  d            0  2020-12-01 00:00:00       1     0.2      0
 1  a            0  2020-12-02 00:00:00       2     0.4      0
 1  b            0  2020-12-02 00:00:00       2     0.4      0
 1  c            0  2020-12-02 00:00:00       2     0.4      0
 1  d            0  2020-12-02 00:00:00       2     0.4      0
 2  a            0  2020-12-03 00:00:00       5     5        1
 2  b            0  2020-12-03 00:00:00       5     5        1
 2  c            0  2020-12-03 00:00:00       5     5        1
 2  d            0  2020-12-03 00:00:00       5     5        1
 3  a            1  2020-12-03 00:00:00       6     1        1
 3  b            1  2020-12-03 00:00:00       6     1        1
 3  c            0  2020-12-03 00:00:00       6     1        1
 3  d            0  2020-12-03 00:00:00       6     1        1
 4  a            0  2020-12-03 00:00:00       5     1        1
 4  b            1  2020-12-03 00:00:00       5     1        1
 4  c            0  2020-12-03 00:00:00       5     1        1
 4  d            0  2020-12-03 00:00:00       5     1        1
 5  a            0  2020-12-05 00:00:00       2     0.3      1
 5  b            0  2020-12-05 00:00:00       2     0.3      1
 5  c            0  2020-12-05 00:00:00       2     0.3      1
 5  d            0  2020-12-05 00:00:00       2     0.3      1
 6  a            1  2020-12-07 00:00:00       3     6        2
 6  b            0  2020-12-07 00:00:00       3     6        2
 6  c            1  2020-12-07 00:00:00       3     6        2
 6  d            0  2020-12-07 00:00:00       3     6        2
 7  a            0  2020-12-08 00:00:00       8     7        2
 7  b            1  2020-12-08 00:00:00       8     7        2
 7  c            0  2020-12-08 00:00:00       8     7        2
 7  d            1  2020-12-08 00:00:00       8     7        2
 8  a            0  2020-12-08 00:00:00       7     1        2
 8  b            0  2020-12-08 00:00:00       7     1        2
 8  c            1  2020-12-08 00:00:00       7     1        2
 8  d            0  2020-12-08 00:00:00       7     1        2
 9  a            0  2020-12-10 00:00:00       4     1        2
 9  b            0  2020-12-10 00:00:00       4     1        2
 9  c            0  2020-12-10 00:00:00       4     1        2
 9  d            0  2020-12-10 00:00:00       4     1        2
10  a            0  2020-12-11 00:00:00       3     0        3
10  b            0  2020-12-11 00:00:00       3     0        3
10  c            0  2020-12-11 00:00:00       3     0        3
10  d            1  2020-12-11 00:00:00       3     0        3
```

Now we are ready to aggregate by dgr, abcd and label as required

```
df2[['col1','col2']] = df2[['col1','col2']].mul(df2['incl'],axis=0)
df3 = df2.groupby(['dgr','abcd']).agg(sum).reset_index()
df3[['col1','col2']] = df3[['col1','col2']].div(df3['incl'],axis=0).fillna(0)
df3['date'] = df3['dgr'].map(lambda g: timeintervals[g+1] + timedelta(days = -1))
df3.drop(columns = ['incl','dgr'])
```

for the final output

```
    abcd      col1    col2  date
--  ------  ------  ------  ----------
 0  a          0       0    2020-12-02
 1  b          0       0    2020-12-02
 2  c          0       0    2020-12-02
 3  d          0       0    2020-12-02
 4  a          6       1    2020-12-06
 5  b          5.5     1    2020-12-06
 6  c          0       0    2020-12-06
 7  d          0       0    2020-12-06
 8  a          3       6    2020-12-10
 9  b          8       7    2020-12-10
10  c          5       3.5  2020-12-10
11  d          8       7    2020-12-10
12  a          0       0    2020-12-20
13  b          0       0    2020-12-20
14  c          0       0    2020-12-20
15  d          3       0    2020-12-20
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I am trying to replicate the process on a real dataset. Unfortunately I get an error at the first step "ValueError: True is not in list". Why that? Thanks again!

Comment: Could it be that there are no rows for a time interval? How can I take that into account?

Comment: Best if you narrow the problem to a small example and then we would be able to help, otherwise very hard

Comment: I figured it out. The problem arises if some row has a date outside time intervals. Therefore I am using `df = df[(df['date']>=min(timeintervals)) & (df['date']<max(timeintervals))]` to filter them out.

Comment: makes sense, yes

Comment: Now the problem is in the join step. I get a memory error message under Windows: _MemoryError: Unable to allocate 34.8 GiB for an array with shape (122, 38246088) and data type float64_. My real dataset has more than 168,000 rows and 356 columns. Out of these columns, 228 are listed in the _groupcol_ var. Len of _timeintervals_ is 313. I am using Python 3.8.5, 64bit. Is there another approach I could use to avoid the memory error?

Comment: A simple solution would be to split your original df into smaller chunks (by time interval, for example) and apply this logic to each chunk separately? It sounds like a lot of data, I would also think again whether what you are trying to do here is really the only way to accomplish whatever end goal you have

Comment: Many thanks for thinking of that! :) In my original approach I was using a double loop, filtering a partial df every time and then aggregating with _pd.concat_ . However, this was taking a lot of time for big datasets and it was giving me an error in some cases that I still need to investigate.